# Titanium Android : Facebook dialog image URL not properly formatted

Tags: android, facebook, titanium

I developing an **Android** application using **Titanium** Appcelerator. I had tried to Post text and Image via facebook feed dialog
.. But error while load my local image URL..

> var fileimg = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(backupDir.nativePath, "myimg.jpg");

```
           var fb_data1 = {
                description : "Some good text",
                picture : fileimg.nativePath,
                link : "www.googlee.com",
            };

            facebook_qfav.dialog("feed", fb_data1, showRequestResult);
```

> function showRequestResult(e) {

```
    var s = '';
    if (e.success) {
        s = "SUCCESS";
        if (e.result) {
            s += "; " + e.result;
        }
        if (e.data) {
            s += "; " + e.data;
        }
        if (!e.result && !e.data) {
            s = '"success",but no data from FB.I am guessing you cancelled the dialog.';
        }   
    } else if (e.cancelled) {
        s = "CANCELLED";
    } else {
        s = "FAILED ";
        if (e.error) {
            s += "; " + e.error;
            alert("facebook Share " + s);
        }
    }
}
```

*ERROR*: **"Image URL not properly formatted"**

*File path will be like this:* **file:///storage/sdcard0/myimg.jpg**

But if i pass the remote URL to the picture property , the image is shown in the dialog...
what happens to the local URL..?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only issue is that `nativepath` has capital P in it. so, its : `nativePath`

so instead of `picture : fileimg.nativepath`, It Should be `picture : fileimg.nativePath,`

[Documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem.File-property-nativePath).

Hope it helps.

Comment: it is asking like a URI path for this picture.. how should i convert it

Comment: can you give me an example.

Comment: No, it doesn't work.. instead of local path, if i pass the remote image location it works perfectly.. i dont what should i do.

Comment: Okay, think you should do something like this :

`var f= Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(backupDir.nativePath, "myimg.jpg");
var blob = f.read();
var data = {
    message: 'This is a Picture',
    picture: blob
};`

Comment: this is according to [Titanium facebook Module](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Modules.Facebook)

Comment: No , this also didn't work.. we cant directly push the image to this property ..have to pass location only..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61327/discussion-between-dragon-and-ganeshkumar).